# NGINX: How do I return the same content but rewrite the URL to remove parameters for good SEO?

Tags: nginx, parameters, url-rewriting

As I understand it, a rewrite will perform a redirect without a response to the user;

```
**Rewrite**
rewrite ^/url_org /url_org/dir permanent;

**Redirect** 
location /url_org {
    return 301 /url_org/dir;
}
```

So in both cases the Resp URL path = /url_org/dir from Server to Client.

Is there a way that you can rewrite /url_org?id=20 so that the content returned is the same but the rewritten url is /url_org/dir? In other words; return the same content but drop the parameter in the URL?

I was expecting that I could rewrite the URL to be SEO friendly but deliver the same content.

Comment: For seo this is solved using the canonical url (`<link rel="canonical" href="...">`). No matter what queryParams you have, search engines regard all pages with the same canonical url as the same page

Comment: On top of this, you can add **hreflang** tags to your pages to indicate what urls contain the same content in another language. All these alternate pages should have the same canonical url tag